# output of filelist and loops for selection of data: moving to next file

Tags: r, loops, filelist

I have a problem with my script on R.

I am working on a list of file and each of these files has a column "date" and also "week" with the number of the week matching with the date.

I would like to save all of this data per week: 1 file for the week 1 of the year, 1 file for the week 2, etc.

I wrote a script to do so. The goal is also to have as output (write.table) with the number of the week in the name of the file, ie. data_2014_week_1 for the first week of the year.

The script is working well for the first week of the year, but I can not have the second and the 50 other weeks.

Here is the script:

```
rm(list = ls())
#
setwd("C:/Users/florent/Documents/R/data")
fileList <- list.files(pattern="scope_ais_.*\\.csv", recursive=TRUE)
i=1
for (file in fileList){
data_2014<-read.table(file, header=T, fill=T, sep=",", nrows=20000)

for (i in 1:51){

data_2014<-data_2014[data_2014$week == i, ]
nrow<-as.numeric(nrow(data_2014))  
    if(nrow>0){
      #data_2014_scope <-     data_2014_scope[order(data_2014_scope$timestamp_pretty) , ]
      dir.create(file.path("C:/Users/florent/Documents/R/data/weeks"),     showWarnings=F)
      directory_divisions=paste("C:/Users/florent/Documents/R/data/weeks/data_2014_wee    k", sep="_",i, ".csv")
      write.table (data_2014, directory_divisions, row.names=F, sep=",")
      #i=i+1  
    } else {
#i=i+1     
}} }
```

I have tried i=i+1 to move to the next week but I can not find the solution.

Any help is welcome!

Comment: `for (i in 1:51)` should move to `i=2` in the second iteration. If you insert `browser()` right after the second loop, you'll be able to monitor what is going on as the looping progresses (press `c` to move loop one iteration).

Comment: Maybe consider using `for (i in unique(data_2014$week))` and then just include the three statements nested in your `if (nrow>0)` statement.

Comment: That worked, thank you!